# MicrosoftAppIdSettingName is BotID?

Tags: botframework

When using bot authentication, i must specify needed parameters to make bot works properly.

MicrosoftAppIdSettingName is BotID actually or ??

Picture : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the name of the Setting in web.config which has the Microsoft AppId for the bot. See [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/d2a/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_bot_authentication.html#a8495aaccbf3b7eb3f71a4b7a55b48d9b).

Comment: So according to this, MicrosoftAppPasswordSettingName is MicrosoftAppPassword ??

Comment: No. Read my response and also read carefully the documentation. It's the name of the setting in the web.config for app name.